# two basic questions about MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am a developer previously working on SQL Server and Windows platform. I am learning MySQL on Windows platform. I have two basic questions which does not find definite answer yet,

1. Does MySQL support T-SQL to write store procedure? If not, are there similar technologies to T-SQL in MySQL world (I am referring to stable/mature technologies);
2. If I download lastest MySQL version (version 5.1), does it support transaction or not (I heard MySQL does not support transaction before)?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. T-SQL: It doesn't have a specific name, but yes, it supports stored procedures and functions ([Manual Chapter 19](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-views.html))
2. Transactions: Yes, MySQL supports them in some of its [storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/) (InnoDB, for instance). Some storage engines don't support them (MyISAM, for instance), but you can just not use those.

When working with MySQL, I always have a bookmark available for directly accessing the (in my opinion) very good [Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/).

Comment: I am not sure whether writing store procedure using T-SQL is much powerful/comprehensive than writing store procedure on MySQL? Or almost the same difficulty to implement the same feature using store procedure?

Comment: T-SQL is only the name of a dialect of SQL supported by SQL Server, it is not in itself anything to do with stored procedures. MySQL does not speak T-SQL. MySQL stored procedures are based on the ANSI SQL/PSM standard. There are syntax differences between SQL/PSM and T-SQL's implementation of stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, in the latest version there is full support for Stored Procedure.

2) Yes, it is supported.

Comment: Store procedure is not the same as T-SQL. I am not sure whether writing store procedure using T-SQL is much powerful than writing store procedure on MySQL?

Comment: Yes, the stored procedure can be written in T-SQL. (http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.html)